# Short footnotes in columns

Tags: footnotes

When there are many short footnotes on one page, it looks bad to use a whole
line for each. Classical typography solves this problem by arranging
consecutive short footnotes in columns (the number of columns varying according
to the number and order of short footnotes on each page). How would one do this
in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  $^1$\,First footnote.\kern .75in & $^2$\,Second.\kern .75in & $^3$\,Third.\kern .75in\\
  $^4$\,Fourth.\kern .75in         & $^5$\,Fifth.\kern .75in  & $^6$\,Sixth.\kern .75in
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(I used \kern because I don’t know how to distribute columns horizontally evenly; but of course that is what should be done.)

[image: Compiled]

When there is one or more footnotes on a page, that are considerably shorter than one line but longer than half a line, they should be centered and aligned.

[image: ex. 2]

[image: ex. 3]

[image]

Comment: @Lawrence: I think, your question is pretty unclear!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I’m sorry but I really don’t see how.

Comment: Each footnote is a float, and as such has to take up an entire page (or column, but each column acts as a separate page).  One would have to bypass the normal processing, yet still reserve space at the bottom of the page (one blank footnote which keeps getting bigger).

Comment: footmisc, manyfoot and bigfoot offer a "para"-footnote style. There is also dblfnote for twocolumn footnotes. See also http://www.ctan.org/topic/footnote

Comment: Thank you, but neither of those is quite what I seek.

Comment: I would have bet quite a bit that nobody has ever done this in print. If we ever meet, i'll get you a beer. I would *never* ever do it (at least for a serious document).

Comment: It can imho be done: Use a para style. Patch footnote so that is measures its argument, and then put them in sensible sized boxes. But it  imho need quite some work to get all the details right (e.g. to get the footnotemarks at the correct places). And you will probably loose the ability of large footnotes to break across pages.

Comment: @Lawrence sorry but really you did not explain what you want well. Now, this is some thing else.

Comment: Maybe the way to go is to have two kinds of footnotes: short three word footnotes, and longer ones. The author has to decide, which one is needed, so we have `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB`, *which both use the same counter for numbering the footnotes.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\let\oldfootnoteA\footnoteA
\renewcommand{\footnoteA}[1]{%
\oldfootnoteA{\makebox[.32\dimexpr\textwidth-2\footglue\relax][l]{#1}}} % adjust .305\textwidth


\begin{document}

Hello\footnoteA{This is some text.}
World\footnoteA{And footnote.}.

\lipsum[1]

Hello\footnoteA{This is some.}
World\footnoteA{And footnote.}.

\lipsum[1]

Hello\footnoteA{This is some.}
World\footnoteA{And footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Why exactly .305\textwidth ?

Comment: @Lawrence this to be adjusted. normally it's 1/3=.33333.... but there is some extrat space separe footnote so. One can compute the exact value.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, just put `\lipsum` into one of the footnotes and you'll see. Why don't you (Lawrence) just stick to the out-of-the-box solution of bigfoot? You get the bigfoot manual by `texdoc bigfoot` on the command line. Footnote issues are ... complicated.

Comment: @KeksDose you're right. But here the question title `Short footnotes in columns`

Comment: @Lawrence i edited my answer `.305\textwidth` replaced with `.32\dimexpr\textwidth-2\footglue\relax`

Comment: where is big footnote (in image ^1 footnote is long 3 columst)

Comment: @MarekKaski please read comments :-)