# Four columns footnotes in a two columns layout

Tags: xetex, footnotes

Is it possible to get 4 columns footnotes in a 2 columns layout?
And also frame a thin line around the footnotes zone?

A layout like this:

[image]

That's what I achieved:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.5in, paperheight=9in, top=0in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[letter,center,cam]{crop}
% formatage marges, etc.
\setlength{\voffset}{0in} % offset haut
\setlength{\hoffset}{0in} % offset gauche
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % marge en tête
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in} % marge texte gauche
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in} % marge texte droite
\setlength{\textheight}{7.5in} % hauteur du texte
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in} % largeur du texte
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} % épaisseur séparateur colonne
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} % espace entre paragraphes

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont{Roboto Condensed}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setcounter{collectmore}{-1}
% entête de base
\pagestyle{myheadings}
% césures - niveau de liberté
\sloppy\hyphenpenalty=2000
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\ShortTitle}[1]{\def\BookName{#1}\par\goodbreak\bigskip\setcounter{footnote}{0}}
\newcommand{\BookTitle}[1]{\par\goodbreak\bigskip{\parindent=0mm\begin{center}{\small\bfseries{\LARGE #1\nopagebreak}}\end{center}}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}\nopagebreak\par\nobreak}
\newcommand{\Chap}[1]{\def\ChapNum{#1}\def\VerseNum{1}}
\newcommand{\VerseOne}{\markboth{\BookName~\ChapNum.1}{\BookName~\ChapNum.1}\lettrine[nindent=0pt, lines=2, lraise=0, loversize=0.33, depth=0]{\textsf{\ChapNum}}}
\newcommand{\VS}[1]{\markboth{\BookName~\ChapNum.#1}{\BookName~\ChapNum.#1}\def\VerseNum{#1}{\up{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} % repères alphabetiques
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\hrule width \textwidth} % longueur ligne
\newcommand{\Note}[1]{\ifnum\value{footnote}>25\setcounter{footnote}{0}\fi\footnote{~#1}}
\newcounter{TitleVerseNum}
\newcommand{\TitleNote}[1]{\ifnum\value{footnote}>25\setcounter{footnote}{0}\fi\setcounter{TitleVerseNum}{\VerseNum}\ifnum\value{TitleVerseNum}>1\addtocounter{TitleVerseNum}{1}\fi\footnote{[\NoAutoSpaceBeforeFDP{\ChapNum.\theTitleVerseNum}]~#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{\subsection*{\centering\footnotesize\normalfont #1}\PP}
\newcommand{\ssubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection*{\centering\scriptsize\normalfont #1}\PP}
\newcommand{\TextTitle}[1]{\ssubsection{\textsf{\normalsize\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\TextRef}[1]{\ssubsubsection{[\textit{#1}]}}

\newcommand{\BFont}{\normalfont\small}
\newcommand{\PP}{\par\parindent=0mm}
\newcommand{\PPE}{\par\parindent=4mm}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% en-tête vide
\makeatletter
\def\@evenhead{}
\def\@oddhead{}
\makeatother

% en-tête pages
\makeatletter
\def\@evenhead{{\NoAutoSpaceBeforeFDP{\small\sc{\rightmark\hfil\thepage\hfil\leftmark}}}}
\def\@oddhead{{\NoAutoSpaceBeforeFDP{\small\sc{\rightmark\hfil\thepage\hfil\leftmark}}}}
\makeatother

\clearpage\input{structure/01-Genese}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My search was unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with an MWE! Do you need those lines in between?

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand your "MWE" (i am a french speaker). 
Yes the gutter line is need. 
Thanks !

Comment: This is an old question, but I would consider printing the footnotes as one single paragraph. For instance by using the [footmisc](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package like this: `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`. The benefit of this should be obvious (using space more efficiently and preventing large rivers), but the layout may already have been decided upon of course.

Answer (score 1):

Alain, if you really only need short footnotes – like verse references or single, short sentences – you may be able to use the solution described here: [Short footnotes in columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266699/short-footnotes-in-columns)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Regarding Bible verses and your MWE: It looks great! Can you tell us a little about your project? (Or at least please contact me in private, see contact info in my profile). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks bik0z for your answer! But i realy need four columns. 
I work in a christian Publishing House and this project is a subcontract. I'd like to use the beauty of LaTeX for this one and maybe other project.
If you have any other ideas this would be great! I will look the manyfoot, bigfoot documentation.

(English is not my natural language ;)