# Group footnotes into columns on one page only

Tags: footnotes, manyfoot

*TL;DR. I want to have certain footnotes (but not all) set in a two-column format. I don't mind managing this semi-manually (e.g. making sure only one type of note appears on a page).*

I have a long document, and in one section, I have a whole string of very short footnotes (currently 12; they are short URLs), which mostly fall on the same page. This obviously leaves a very tall and odd looking footer on the page.
I would like to have the footnotes grouped into columns for this page/area only (as I have long footnotes elsewhere which need to take the full width).

All the related questions I have been able to find relate to setting footnotes in columns for the whole document (e.g. [Split LaTeX footnotes into two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134937/split-latex-footnotes-into-two-columns), `dblfnote`, etc.), or handling footnotes in two-column documents, which is not what I'm looking for.

I eventually came up with the following attempt using `manyfoot` to set certain notes in "paragraph" format and then put them in boxes to look like they are in columns, which gets close. I set `\hangindent` to try to align the second line of notes with the first, but this either works for single or double-digit footnotes (which have different widths) but not both.
It also doesn't seem like the "proper" solution to this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}

% Set up a footnote style which runs all footnotes together in one paragraph.
\SetFootnoteHook{\hangindent=1.1em} % Amount chosen to match double-digit footnotes
\newfootnote[para]{X}
\newcommand{\footnoteXX}{\stepcounter{footnote}\Footnotemark\thefootnote \FootnotetextX{\thefootnote}}
\newcommand{\footnoteX}[1]{\footnoteXX{\makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{5} % Simulate being part-way through the document.

Hello,\footnoteX{AAA} I\footnoteX{BBB} have lots\footnoteX{CCC} of footnotes\footnoteX{DDD} to mention\footnoteX{EEE} on\footnoteX{FFF} a\footnoteX{GGG} single\footnoteX{HHH} page\footnoteX{III}.

\end{document}
```

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266722/112573) to [Short footnotes in columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266699/short-footnotes-in-columns) uses the same approach, with cleverer calculation of the box widths, but the same issue.

---

**Alternative attempt:**
In a MWE, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353306/112573) gives the output I want.
However, I get some conflicts when I add `reledmac` to my actual document (which I can fix), and it also seems to have affected other spacing around footnote marks (and maybe other things?).
I am paranoid about "small" changes like this which are hard to spot, so I am put off this solution, in favour of one which doesn't affect the rest of the document, if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\begin{document}
This is\footnoteA{Left side footnote} a dummy text. Let us find out\footnoteA{Second left side footnote} if it worked well \footnoteA{Right side footnote} or not\footnoteA{Second right side footnote}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, regarding the "alternative attempt", if anyone can suggest a way to tell what effect adding a new package had on the document, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution also puts `\fnmark` into a constant width box.  It uses the width of `\footnotemark[22]` (8.47pt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}

% Set up a footnote style which runs all footnotes together in one paragraph.
%\SetFootnoteHook{\hangindent=\parindent}% constant indentation for every line
\SetFootnoteHook{\parindent=0pt}
\newfootnote[para]{X}
\newcommand{\footnoteXX}{\stepcounter{footnote}\Footnotemark\thefootnote \FootnotetextX{\makebox[8.5pt][r]{\thefootnote}}}
\newcommand{\footnoteX}[1]{\footnoteXX{\makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{5} % Simulate being part-way through the document.

Hello,\footnoteX{AAA} I\footnoteX{BBB} have lots\footnoteX{CCC} of footnotes\footnoteX{DDD} to mention\footnoteX{EEE} on\footnoteX{FFF} a\footnoteX{GGG} single\footnoteX{HHH} page\footnoteX{III}.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Ah, I think this is just what I was looking for. I was so close, and yet so far. Thanks.